# Overriding both list and view of an object with visualforce pages

Tags: visualforce, button-overrides

I'm overriding both the "List" and "View" standard actions on a custom object X, with two visualforce pages "XListView" and "XDetailView". I'm overriding the tab of this object as well, with XListView. I'm using enhancedList on the XListView vf page. While testing I clicked on the X tab, it directed me to "https://c.cs8.visual.force.com/apex/XListView?save_new=1&sfdc.override=1". I have some test records in the listview and I clicked on one of them. This action directed me to the custom detail view of X (XDetailView visualforce page) but the URL is still the same, "https://c.cs8.visual.force.com/apex/XListView?save_new=1&sfdc.override=1". Due to this, if I refresh the detail page or open the parent record (from the detail page) and click on "Back", it's redirecting to the list view of X. Can anyone please help me here on getting "XDetailView" in the URL when I'm on the record detail page?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you may need to hack it and add some JS that adds target="_top" to your detail links.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. I'll try it and see if it fixes this issue.

Comment: It works fine after I added <base target="_top" ></base> to the XListView vf page. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is the answer.

Add target="_top" to your detail links.